# Deploying ADF Essentials application to Glass Fish Server

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, oracle-adf

I am planning to create an application using Oracle ADF Essentials to deploy it on Glass Fish server to avoid the cost of Weblogic license, I need detailed steps for development and deployment, and I need to know how we choose to choose only ADF Essentials only not any commercial features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to
It even has a YouTube video.